# Performance comparison: insert vs build Python set operations 

Tags: python, set, time-complexity

In python, is it faster to 
a) Build a set from a list of n items
b) Insert n items into a set?

I found this page (http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) but it did not have enough information to conclude which was faster.

It seems, inserting items one at a time could in the worst case take O(n*n) time (given it uses dicts), and O(n*1) in the average case. Does initializing a set with a list offer any performance improvement?

Comment: Seems you want to compare building a set from the list against insertion of n items to set, but the first line of question means something different.

Comment: Oops! thanks for pointing that out sateesh.

Comment: It's easy to find out for yourself using `timeit`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In terms of `O()` complexity - it's definitely the same, because both approaches do exactly the same - insert `n` items into a set.

The difference comes from implementation: One clear advantage of initialization from an iterable is that you save a lot of Python-level function calls - the initialization from a iterable is done wholly on the C level (**).

Indeed, some tests on a list of 5,000,000 random integers shows that adding one by one is slower:

```
lst = [random.random() for i in xrange(5000000)]
set1 = set(lst)    # takes 2.4 seconds

set2 = set()       # takes 3.37 seconds
for item in lst:
    set2.add(item)
```

---

(**) Looking inside the code of sets (`Objects/setobject.c`), eventually item insertion boils down to a call to `set_add_key`. When initializing from an iterable, this function is called in a tight C loop:

```
while ((key = PyIter_Next(it)) != NULL) {
  if (set_add_key(so, key) == -1) {
    Py_DECREF(it);
    Py_DECREF(key);
    return -1;
  } 
  Py_DECREF(key);
}
```

On the other hand, each call to `set.add` invokes attribute lookup, which resolves to the C `set_add` function, which in turn calls `set_add_key`. Since the item addition itself is relatively quick (the hash table implementation of Python is *very* efficient), these extra calls all build up.

Comment: The Python loop is much closer in performance than I would have expected, and you can get even closer by creating a local variable containing a reference to `set.add` and calling that in the loop, avoiding the attribute lookup. In my tests, that was only about 15% slower than using the `set()` constructor!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ python -V
Python 2.5.2
$ python -m timeit -s "l = range(1000)" "set(l)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.6 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "l = range(1000)" "s = set()" "for i in l:s.add(i)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 307 usec per loop
```

Comment: You can speedup the 2nd command 2x times by `s_add = s.add`: `python -m timeit -s "l = range(1000)" "s = set(); s_add=s.add" "for i in l:s_add(i)"`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the results from running the comparison using `timeit`. Seems initialization of set using list to be faster, curious to know why it is so:

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit("set(a)","a=range(10)")
# 0.9944498532640864

timeit("for i in a:x.add(i)","a=range(10);x=set()")
# 1.6878826778265648
```

Python version: 2.7

Answer (score 0):

On my Thinkpad:

```
In [37]: timeit.timeit('for a in x: y.add(a)',
                       'y=set(); x=range(10000)', number=10000)
Out[37]: 12.18006706237793

In [38]: timeit.timeit('y=set(x)', 'y=set(); x=range(10000)', number=10000)
Out[38]: 3.8137960433959961
```