# Create a set from items in two lists

Tags: python, list, set

I have the following code:

```
ids = set()
for result in text_results:
    ids.add(str(result[5]))
for result in doc_results:
    ids.add(str(result[4]))
```

Both `text_results` and `doc_results` are lists that contain other lists as items as you might have already guessed. Is there a more efficient way to do this using a nifty oneliner rather than two for loops?

Comment: What's your motivation for wanting a one-liner? I find the current code perfectly readable.

Comment: Your code is good as it is. A one liner is not better in all cases

Comment: @NPE I'm not strictly set on a one-liner but shortening it to two lines seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably write:

```
ids = set(str(result[5]) for result in text_results)
ids.update(str(result[4]) for result in doc_results)
```

As for efficiency, if you want to squeeze every possible bit of performance then you first need a realistic dataset, then you can try things like `map` (or `itertools.imap` in Python 2) and `operator.itemgetter`, to see what's faster.

If you absolutely must have a one-liner:

```
ids = set(itertools.chain((str(result[5]) for result in text_results), (str(result[4]) for result in doc_results)))
```

Although, if you want a one-liner it's also worth optimizing for conciseness so that your one-liner will be readable, and then seeing whether performance is adequate:

```
ids = set([str(x[5]) for x in text_results] + [str(x[4]) for x in doc_results]))
```

This "feels" inefficient because it concatenates two lists, which shouldn't be necessary. But that doesn't mean it really is inefficient for your data, so its worth including in your tests.

Comment: I like your first solution. Thanks, that looks better.

Answer (score 0):

This one liner should work:

```
ids = set(map (lambda x: str(x[4]), doc_results) + map(lambda x: str(x[5]), text_results))
```

Comment: A one-liner? Definitely. An improvement on the original? I personally am not so sure.

Comment: @NPE , I think that creating the set from a list is probably faster than adding to it one by one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835657/performance-comparison-insert-vs-build-python-set-operations

Comment: @ReutSharabani What about the cost of creating the list?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - I like Steve Jessop's answer. But now I'm wondering how python handles this internally... You're right, creating the list is worth optimizing.

Comment: There is a reasonable concern, that creating either a `set` or a `list` of size that's unknown in advance might be less efficient than one that is, due to the need for reallocations as the data structure grows. If Python 2's `map` and `set` both contain checks whether they can see the size of `doc_results` and `text_results`, and allocate the right size to begin with, then it's entirely possible for this to be faster than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This (wrapped) one liner should work:

```
ids = set([str(tr[5]) for tr in text_results] +
          [str(dr[4]) for dr in doc_results])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
ids = {str(i) for text, doc in zip(text_results, doc_results) for i in (text[5], doc[4])}
```

This is assuming results is something like:

```
text_results = [['t11', 't12', 't13', 't14', 't15', 't16'], ['t21', 't22', 't23', 't24', 't25', 't26']]
doc_results = [['d11', 'd12', 'd13', 'd14', 'd15', 'd16'], ['d21', 'd22', 'd23', 'd24', 'd25', 'd26']]
```

And you want:

```
ids = {'d15', 't26', 't16', 'd25'}
```

Comment: Set comprehension is available in python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a more pythonic way:

```
map(str,set([i[5] for i in text_results]+[i[4] for i in doc_results]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> text_results = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,56,6],[4,5,6,1,2,6,22],[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]]
>>> doc_results = [[1,2,3,4,5,9,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,56,3],[4,5,6,1,2,7,22],[1,2,3,4,5,7,7,9]]
>>> map(str,set([i[5] for i in text_results]+[i[4] for i in doc_results]))
['56', '2', '5', '6', '7']
```